# Fit Image in canvas using WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have canvas with child images. Here is my XAML:

```
<Canvas x:Name="ImageArea" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Image x:Name="BigImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="ImageRotateTransform" Angle="0"/>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageScaleTransform" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1"/>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="ImageTranslateTransform" X="0" Y="0"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
 </Canvas>
```

I want to fit this image in canvas with this code:

```
var fitSize = Math.Max(BigImage.ActualHeight, BigImage.ActualWidth);
var targetSize = Math.Min(ImageArea.ActualHeight, ImageArea.ActualWidth);
var ratio = targetSize / fitSize;
ImageScaleTransform.ScaleX = ImageScaleTransform.ScaleY = ratio;
ImageTranslateTransform.X = 
    fitSize == BigImage.ActualWidth ? 
    0 : ImageArea.ActualWidth / 2 - BigImage.ActualWidth*ratio / 2;
ImageTranslateTransform.Y = 
    fitSize == BigImage.ActualHeight ? 
    0 : ImageArea.ActualHeight / 2 - BigImage.ActualHeight * ratio / 2;
```

This code computes scale ratio, then tries to center image depending of it size.
The problem is that X and Y coordinates of translate transform are computed right but image **not** positioned as expected (only small part of image visible in bottom down of the canvas). If set RenderTransformOrigin to `0,0` image positioned normal.

Where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `Image` is no longer positioned in the upper-left hand corner of the `Canvas` after scaling and so the translation offsets don't appear to be working.

Here is a XAML-only fragment based on your question that has a red `Rectangle` and we've done nothing more than manually set the scale factors to one and a half instead of one:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="ImageArea" ClipToBounds="False" Background="Gray" Width="200" Height="200">
        <Rectangle x:Name="BigImage" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red">
            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="ImageRotateTransform" Angle="0"/>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ImageScaleTransform" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ImageTranslateTransform" X="0" Y="0"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Which produces this result:

[image: Red Rectangle]

This happens because of the `RenderTransformOrigin` setting.  You can leave the property unset or use the value `"0,0"` to keep the upper-left hand corner firmly seated while you scale it.

Answer (score 0):

use a Grid, its relative. Canvas is absolute positioning.

Comment: <Grid><Image Source="?"></Image></Grid>