# Scaling image to canvas parent height in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

I'm new to WPF and trying something simple. I'm making a custom control with a canvas where I have an image that is higher than the canvas. When it displays it overflows the canvas, so I want it to scale to the parent height. There's probably an easy answer but I haven't found it yet.

Here's the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFUserControl.Instance"
             Name="InstanceBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Width="448" Height="99.2">
    <Grid Name="InstanceGrid" Background="White" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="0,0,0,0.2">
        <Canvas>
            <Image 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
                Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Resources/M-Series-single.jpg" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: A Canvas does not resize its child elements, so why use it here? Just remove it and put the Image in the Grid (or in another Grid that is a child of the top-level Grid)

Comment: As the previous comment notes, the `Canvas` element does not resize children. It's strictly a place to put things. WPF has lots of other layout options, but your question is so vague and has so little evidence of research, that it's not clear why you have shown code with the `Canvas` element, never mind whether an answer that accomplishes the desired visual result in a different way would be acceptable.

Comment: There is one related question that is particularly relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196915/fit-image-in-canvas-using-wpf. It includes some example code of how you would do this if you insist on placing the `Image` in the `Canvas` (i.e. you have to scale manually, as seen in that other Q&A). But I don't recommend this approach if you can avoid it; it's better, if you want the `Image` to scale with its container, to give it a container that knows how to do that and has property options for doing so (e.g. `Grid`).

Comment: Note also that you would typically embed an image file as assembly resource, and reference it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx), like `pack://application:,,,/Resources/M-Series-single.jpg` (instead of using `siteoforigin`).

Comment: So I ask the wrong question but get the right answer anyway? Sounds good to me. Y'all are pretty hard on someone just getting into this. I did search quite a bit; it was just for the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of the canvas (because it doesn't measure its children) and instead use the `Stretch` property of the `Image`, you should be able to get the behaviour you require. If not, you might experiment with `ViewBox`.

Comment: No Viewbox required. `Stretch` is set to `Uniform` by default, so you also don't need to set that. Just replace the Canvas by a Grid, or some other control that set the size of its child, e.g. a Border.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use canvas.
2. You can bind to the ActualHeight property of your grid.

The same thing can be done for width

Answer (score 1):

Canvas don't resize childs so if you can you should put Image in a Grid. If you must use a Canvas you can bind the Width and Height of Image to the ActualWidth and ActualHeight of Canvas.

```
<Canvas x:Name="canvas">
    <Image x:Name="image" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=canvas, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=canvas, Mode=OneWay}" Stretch="Fill" />
</Canvas>
```